# DHCP fails on 4th and 5th interface with No DHCPOFFERS received

Tags: networking, dhcp

I just installed a 4 port NIC in my Ubuntu 16.04 server box. The internal network card still works fine and the first 2 ports (any two) work fine on the new card. But no matter what sequence I initialize the interfaces in, the 4th and 5th refuse to get IP addresses and initialize.

I am guessing that there is some limit causing the DHCP process to work correctly on the first three network interfaces but then it fails on the next two.

I have tested by bringing down all but the internal interface (because I am accessing via ssh and I need that interface to connect). Then In use ifup on each interface by hand. It doesn't matter what sequence I bring the interfaces up in, I get two that work and two that fail out of the 4 on the new card.

**ifconfig (notice enp3s0 and enp6s0)**

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:0a:5a  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:a5a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6857 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:111 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:420291 (420.2 KB)  TX bytes:27522 (27.5 KB)

enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:0a:5b  
          inet addr:192.168.1.203  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:a5b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:235024 (235.0 KB)  TX bytes:3006 (3.0 KB)

enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:0a:5c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.115  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:a5c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:751 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:85444 (85.4 KB)  TX bytes:14184 (14.1 KB)

enp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:0a:5d  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:a5d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3554 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:115 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:213789 (213.7 KB)  TX bytes:28890 (28.8 KB)

enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:2b:34:97:d8:53  
          inet addr:192.168.1.112  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::922b:34ff:fe97:d853/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2888736 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3313452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:683422371 (683.4 MB)  TX bytes:1293115042 (1.2 GB)
```

My internal interface is enp7s0 so I can't bring that one down without losing my ssh connection.

But if I bring 3-6 down then back up in a different order, I get a different result.

**ifconfig (notice enp5s0 and enp6s0)**

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:0a:5a  
          inet addr:192.168.1.110  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:a5a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7689 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:470779 (470.7 KB)  TX bytes:28854 (28.8 KB)

enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:0a:5b  
          inet addr:192.168.1.203  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:a5b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3724 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:31 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:246046 (246.0 KB)  TX bytes:4338 (4.3 KB)

enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:0a:5c  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:a5c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:805 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:85 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:90464 (90.4 KB)  TX bytes:16542 (16.5 KB)

enp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:0a:5d  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:a5d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4385 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:133 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:263649 (263.6 KB)  TX bytes:32958 (32.9 KB)

enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:2b:34:97:d8:53  
          inet addr:192.168.1.112  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::922b:34ff:fe97:d853/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2931383 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3358859 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:695890607 (695.8 MB)  TX bytes:1306715847 (1.3 GB)
```

Here is the results of the last **ifup** attempt, I performed the same task with ifdown then ifup having the interfaces in a different sequence each time. Always the last two fail. But the ones that work get good IP addresses. Something seems very off about this.

**sudo ifup enp6s0 enp5s0 enp4s0 enp3s0**

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp6s0/00:e0:4c:68:0a:5d
Sending on   LPF/enp6s0/00:e0:4c:68:0a:5d
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp6s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xd8b27778)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp6s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xd8b27778)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.205 on enp6s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7877b2d8)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.205 from 192.168.1.1
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.205 from 192.168.1.1
bound to 192.168.1.205 -- renewal in 32722 seconds.
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp5s0/00:e0:4c:68:0a:5c
Sending on   LPF/enp5s0/00:e0:4c:68:0a:5c
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x9001ca46)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x9001ca46)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0x9001ca46)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.115 on enp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x46ca0190)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.115 from 192.168.1.1
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.115 from 192.168.1.1
bound to 192.168.1.115 -- renewal in 39657 seconds.
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp4s0/00:e0:4c:68:0a:5b
Sending on   LPF/enp4s0/00:e0:4c:68:0a:5b
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x88fe0427)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x88fe0427)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x88fe0427)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x88fe0427)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp4s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0x88fe0427)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp3s0/00:e0:4c:68:0a:5a
Sending on   LPF/enp3s0/00:e0:4c:68:0a:5a
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xffe5cb17)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0xffe5cb17)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0xffe5cb17)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0xffe5cb17)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0xffe5cb17)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xffe5cb17)
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp7s0
iface enp7s0 inet dhcp

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp
auto enp5s0
iface enp5s0 inet dhcp
auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet dhcp
```

**/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf**

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;

timeout 60;
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really shouldn't have more than one ip-address active on a given subnet (like 192.168.1.xxx). If you need to have more interfaces, running, they should be bond'ed, or on different subnets. Anyway, have you tried to delete unused dhcp-leases on your dhcp-server .. if it is a home-setup it's probably your router.

Comment: I agree with @SorenA.  What are you trying to accomplish with more than one interface here?  Load balancing?  Bonding?  Fail-over?  VLAN?  You should not have more than one IP in the same subnet going to the system.

Comment: Primarily, I am just testing right now. I wanted to be sure that all the interfaces were working properly. And they clearly are. I have seen (but really don't understand why) it is not a great idea to have multiple interfaces with the same subnet. But it still seems very weird that the first three interfaces properly get IP addresses assigned then they start failing. I am sure it is not the DHCP server (my router) because there are a ton of addresses available. I am using a total of 14 of the 100+ I have available. And I know I can keep getting more because I tested that from other computers.

Comment: Ultimately, I want to set up bonding but I was having an issue so I wanted to test all the interfaces to eliminate that as an issue. So this has become somewhat academic but I would still like to understand what is going on to cause the DHCP to stop working once three IP addresses are assigned.